# Please explain this python behavior

Tags: python, initialization

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, key_text_pairs = None):
        .....
        for key, text in key_text_pairs:
            ......
            ......

x = SomeClass([(1, "abc",), (2, "fff",)])
```

The value of key_text_pairs inside the **init** is None even if I pass a list as in the above statement. Why is it so??

I want to write a generic **init** which can take all  iterator objects...

Thanks

Edit: oops.. I wanted to pass key value pair in the form of tuple... I was just trying to create a toy example.. I am still seeing the same behavior

Comment: to begin with you are using `dict` syntax on a list

Comment: Can you provide an interactive interpreter example please?

Comment: FYI, if `key_text_pairs` is a `dict`, and you wanted to loop over it, use `for key, text in key_text_pairs.items():`. That said, you say "I want to write a generic **init** which can take all iterator objects," but you seem to mean "I want to write a generic `__init__` which can take all iterables *which yield a 2-tuple at a time*."  Is this true, or are there other things you want to accept?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you say `for key, text in key_text_pairs`, you are implying that the list has tuples. I tested your code exactly the way it is and that's what happened.

Change `x = SomeClass([1, 2, 3])` to `x = SomeClass([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0)])` and see if that helps

Cheers

Comment: @StackUnderflow: You made the change, did it help?

Comment: It most certainly did. However, I am unclear as to what you would like your function to do since you have omitted the body of your functions. Therefore, I made my change on a version of __init__ that simply prints the values. For that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So just looking at that code, is what you posted exactly what you want?  Specifically, if you're passing in a list that looks like:

`[1, 2, 3]`

Then I don't think you want to try to extract it like this:

`for key, text in key_text_pairs`

You can extract a list of individual integers into a pair of values like key/text.

If I run that code as you posted it, I get a stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    x = SomeClass([1, 2, 3])
  File "test.py", line 3, in __init__
    for key, text in key_text_pairs:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You either need to do something like this (extract one value at a time):

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, key_text_pairs = None):
        for key in key_text_pairs:
            ....

x = SomeClass([1, 2, 3])
```

Or your original list needs to change to be holding pairs of values if you're going to keep that code the same:

`x = SomeClass([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)])`

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a traceback?

This is what I get when I run the code:

```
In [1]: class SomeClass(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, key_text_pairs = None):
   ...:         for key, text in key_text_pairs:
   ...:             print "key:", key, "text", text
   ...:             
   ...:             

In [2]: x = SomeClass([1,2,3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/ryan/<ipython console> in <module>()

/home/ryan/<ipython console> in __init__(self, key_text_pairs)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

In [3]: x = SomeClass(zip('abc', [1,2,3]))
key: a text 1
key: b text 2
key: c text 3
```